# Error connecting firestore to redux store despite correct setup

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, redux-thunk

I'm trying to display a list of documents I have stored in firestore in react with redux. However despite setting up my store and my actions it appears react cannot find the `firestore` object which results in errors such as `cannot call map() of undefined`.

I believe I have everything setup correctly according to the latest documentation from `react-redux : v6` and `react-redux-firebase : v3` but they just don't seem to want to play nice together! I've poured through my code but can't find the issue:

## App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {
  createFirestoreInstance,
  getFirestore,
  reduxFirestore,
} from 'redux-firestore';
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore();
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunk.withExtraArgument({
        getFirebase,
        getFirestore,
      })
    ),
    reduxFirestore(firebase)
  )
);

const rrfConfig = {
  useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
};
const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance, // <- needed if using firestore
};
function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <Dashboard></Dashboard>
        </div>
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## Root reducer

```js
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import postReducer from './postReducer';

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { firestoreReducer, firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  postData: postReducer,
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

## Actions

While I have a defined action for creating a post (that works),
I cannot access the `ordered` property of the `firestore` object,
which is how I believe I can access collections of documents?

```js
export const createProject = (post: { [key: string]: any }) => {
  return (dispatch: Function, getState: any, { _, getFirestore }: any) => {
    //anyc code start
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    firestore
      .collection('posts')
      .add({
        ...post,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'CREATE_POST',
          post: post,
        });
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        //dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_POST_ERROR', error: err });
        console.log(err);
      });
    //async code end
  };
};
```

## PostTable

This is where I'm actually trying to display the posts:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';

const PostTable = (props: { [key: string]: any }) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <table className="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.posts.map((post: { [key: string]: any }) => {
          return (
            <tr key={post.id}>
              <th scope="row">{post.id}</th>
              <td>{post.title}</td>
              <td>{post.content}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: { [key: string]: any }) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    posts: state.firestore.ordered.posts,
  };
};

export const PostTableCompose = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    {
      collection: 'posts',
    },
  ])
)(PostTable) as React.ComponentType;
```